# Quicksight data from Athena for correct TimeStamp

Tags: sql, timestamp, amazon-quicksight, amazon-athena

I am trying to use date time in AWS quicksight from Athena and parse it out from each file name (paht) that has a format like this '2022-06-02 19:26:48.491730xxxxx'

Using this

```
date(date_format(AT_TIMEZONE(cast (regexp_extract("$path", '\w{4}-\w{2}-\w{2} \w{2}:\w{2}:\w{2}.w{6}') as timestamp),'America/Los_Angeles'),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:SSSSSS'))  AS time_stamp,
```

I get null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
date_parse(date_format(AT_TIMEZONE(cast (regexp_extract("$path", '\w{4}-\w{2}-\w{2} \w{2}:\w{2}:\w{2}') as timestamp),'America/Los_Angeles'),'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'),'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')  AS time_stamp
```